# second order non-homogenous ODE with undetermined coefficients...stuck

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

$$y'''+y''=x + e^{-x}$$

$$y_{h}= C_1 + C_2 e^{-x}$$

Since there is duplication I think I should have my particular system set up as:

$$y_p= Ax^2+Bx+Cxe^{-x}$$

$$y_p'= 2Ax + B - Cxe^{-x}$$

$$y_p'' = 2A + Cxe^{-x}$$

$$y_p''' = -Ce^{-x}$$

Plugging all this in I get:

$$-Ce^{-x} + 2A + Ce^{-x}= Ax + b + Ce^{-x}$$

I don't understand what I am doing wrong here i am following all the steps that should be taking

Comment: check the derivatives of $y_p$...

Comment: Integrate the given ODE twice in order to obtain a first order DE. Then apply the integrating factor method.

Answer (score 1):

The rule is that if

- you have a term $p(x)e^{rx}$ on the right and
- $r$ is a root of multiplicity $m$ of the characteristic polynomial of the left side,

then the trial solution is $$x^mq(x)e^{rx}$$ where the degree of $q$ is the degree of $p$ and the coefficients of $q$ belong to the set of undetermined coefficients.

This also holds for $r=0$, that is, purely polynomial terms on the right side, and correspondingly missing lower order derivatives on the left side.

This means that the trial solution is
$$
y(x)=x^2(Ax+B)+x^1Ce^{-x}.
$$