# non-homogenous linear ODE help

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y^{(3)}+y''=x+e^{-x}$$

I don't understand what I am doing wrong? after finding the characteristic polynomial there is a repeat with $e^{-x}$ setting up my particulars:

$y_{p_1}=Ax+B, y_{p_2}= xe^{-x}$ but none of these leads to an answer...

Comment: Why did you feel it necessary to repeat the identical question [second order non-homogenous ODE with undetermined coefficients…stuck](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3400644/115115)?

Comment: There are now three answers to this question. Can you solve the problem through one of the three answers?

Answer (score 1):

Start reducing the order : $p=y''$ and solve
$$p'+p=e^x+x$$ for which the general equation is
$$p=c_1 e^{-x}+e^{-x} x+x-1$$ Integrate twice.